# Is the Holy Spirit called God in Luke 1:35?

Tags: luke, referent-identification, christology, pneumatology, son-of-god

Luke 1:35 contains the following statement from the angel Gabriel (NKJV):

> **The Holy Spirit** will come upon you, and the power of the Highest will overshadow you; **therefore**, also, that Holy One who is to be born will be called **the Son of God**.

This concept of Mary conceiving through the Holy Spirit is also taught in Matthew 1:18-20. Does Luke 1:35 connect Jesus' being called "the Son of God" with Mary conceiving through the Holy Spirit? If so, does this suggest that, in a sense, Jesus is the Son of **the Holy Spirit**, which is interchangeable with being the Son of **God**--equating "the Holy Spirit" with "God"?

For clarification, I am not asking if the Holy Spirit is the same as God the Father. Rather, is "God" in Luke 1:35 referring to the Holy Spirit?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. This is not an argument against the Deity of the Holy Spirit, rather, a proposal that this verse takes no position on the subject.

Compare to Ephesians 3:16

> I pray that from his glorious, unlimited resources he will empower you
> with inner strength through his Spirit.

God does many things through the power of the Spirit--the Bible contains many examples of people being inspired, strengthened, changed by God--and the medium He employs to carry this out is the Holy Spirit.

Answer (score 1):

It is an ancient aphorism that, "Nothing so ruins a good case as when it is overstated."  This is true of the claim in the present question about the Holy Spirit.

As far as the divinity or otherwise of the Holy Spirit as taught or otherwise in Luke 1:35, we can see this in two ways:

1. Luke 1:35 is used by some trinitarians as evidence of the divinity of the Holy Spirit.  The same text is used by Binitarians and Arians to disprove the personhood of the Holy Spirit.  This should raise our suspicions greatly.
2. The text of Luke 1:35 is written in qunitessential Hebrew parallelism as follows:

- A: (1) The Holy Spirit (2) will come on you
- B: (1) The power of the Most High (2) will overshadow you

Note that Holy Spirit is equivalent to "the power of the Most High".

This is precisely why Binitarians and Arians use this text to demonstrate that the Holy Spirit is merely the power of God and not a person.  However, such a conclusion ignores much other material that does not deny this claim but shows that the Holy Spirit is much more than this.

**CONCLUSION**

However, that the Holy Spirit is the power of the God= Most High is all than can be deduced from Luke 1:35.

**APPENDIX - Person of the Holy Spirit and Divinity**

While Luke 1:35 says nothing about the divinity of personhood of the Holy Spirit, there is much else that does.

Implicit Statements

- Acts 5:3, 4 equates lying to God and lying to the Holy Spirit
- Acts 10:38 equates the Holy Spirit with the presence of God
- Comparing Rom 1:2-6 and 16:26 we find that The Holy Spirit has the authority of God
- 1 Cor 12:4-6 equates the Holy Spirit with the one Lord and God
- Job 33:4, Eze 37:14, Rom 8:2, 10, attributes the source of life to the Holy Spirit
- Titus 3:4-6, 1 Peter 1:2 attributes the Holy Spirit as the source of spiritual life
- Psalm 104:30 and Gen 1:2 both declare the Holy Spirit as the creator
- Heb 9:14 also declares the Holy Spirit an essential part of Salvation.
- 2 Cor 3:17 calls the Holy Spirit “Lord”.
- Comparing Isa 63:10 with Num 14:11 shows that grieving the Holy Spirit is equivalent to grieving God.

The Bible assumes that the Holy Spirit is divine in many instances.

- Compare Isa 63:10 with Num 14:11 & Deut 32:12 – The Holy Spirit spurned/grieved is equivalent to God being grieved.  In the NT we have Acts 7:51 where Stephen accuses the Jews of resisting the Holy Spirit!  Paul tells us not to quench the Holy Spirit (1 Thess 5:19) and not to grieve the Holy Spirit (Eph 4:30).  See also Acts 15:28 where the divine guidance of the Holy Spirit is highly valued.
- 2 Sam 23:2, 3 makes clear that the Holy Spirit speaking is the voice of God
- 1 Cor 3:16, 17, 6:19, 20 – the indwelling Holy Spirit is a divine presence
- 1 Cor 12:11, 28 – the Holy Spirit distributing gifts is equivalent to the will of God
- The Holy Spirit is essential to the plan of salvation through washing/rebirth (Tit 3:4-6, 1 Peter 1:2), giving spiritual life (Rom 8:2, 9, 11)
- The Holy Spirit is the agent of Scriptural inspiration (Acts 28:25-27, 2 Peter 1:21, 2 Tim 3:16, 17)

We should also note that the Bible affirms all the usual attributes of divinity to the Holy Spirit of being omniscient (1 Cor 2:10, 11), omnipresent (Ps 139:7), eternal (Heb 9:14, cf 1 Tim 6:16), omnipotent (Luke 1:35, Rom 15:19, Zech 4:6), etc, except, veneration.  There is neither Bible command nor example of veneration of the Holy Spirit.  The reason is not difficult to find – the function of the Holy Spirit is to bring glory to Jesus and teach us about Jesus (John 16:13, 14).  Thus, while the Holy Spirit is God, our attention is constantly turned to Jesus.

Three Persons

Matt 3:16, 17, 28:19, Mark 1:10,11, Luke 3:21, 22, John 1:32, 14:26, 15:26-16:14, Acts 10:38, Rom 1:2-4, 1 Cor 6:11, 12:2, 3, 2 Cor 13:14, Gal 3:11-14, Heb 9:14, 10:29, 1 Peter 1:2, 3, 4:14.  Note that these passages refer to the Holy Spirit as a separate person distinct from the Father and Son.  The most unambiguous case of this is when the sin of blasphemy is discussed (see below).

Personhood

The passages in John 15:26 – 16:14 repeatedly talk about the Holy Spirit as a separate person from either the Father or Jesus.

1 Cor 2:10, 11 (see also Isa 40:13, 14) also identifies the Holy Spirit as a separate person because of His teaching and instructing function.  See also Rom 15:19 and Ps 104:30.

In Matt 12:31, 32, Mark 3:28, 29, and Luke 12:8-10 the unforgivable sin is defined as blasphemy against the Holy Spirit.  This is an expansion of Isa 63:10-14 where people grieved the Holy Spirit.  Such a sin would not be even possible if the Holy Spirit were not both a person and divine.  Note further, that these passages make a clear distinction between sinning against the Son or Father as opposed to the Holy Spirit, again, showing that the Holy Spirit is a distinct person.

In 1 Cor 12:11 it is the Holy Spirit who decides about spiritual gifts and their distribution.  This passage attributes volition and sentience to the person of the Holy Spirit.

In Acts 7:51, 1 Thess 5:19, Eph 4:30 we have various people resisting or spurning the Holy Spirit and in Acts 15:28 the Holy Spirit’s opinion is consulted.
Possibly the best verses to demonstrate the individuality and personhood of the Holy Spirit is found in Rom 8:26, 27, which says –

In the same way, the Spirit helps us in our weakness.  For we do not know how we ought to pray, but the Spirit Himself intercedes for us with groans too deep for words.  And He who searches our hearts knows the mind of the Spirit, because the Spirit intercedes for the saints according to the will of God.

Blasphemy Against the Holy Spirit and the Unforgivable Sin

The NT makes an interesting claim about the sin of blasphemy against the Holy Spirit in Matt 12:31, 32, Mark 3:28, 29, and Luke 12:8-10.  This sin, it appears, cannot be forgiven.

> And so I tell you, every kind of sin and slander can be forgiven, but
> blasphemy against the Spirit will not be forgiven.  Anyone who speaks
> a word against the Son of Man will be forgiven, but anyone who speaks
> against the Holy Spirit will not be forgiven, either in this age or in
> the age to come. Matt 12:31, 32.

One cannot blaspheme a non-existent person, so the Holy Spirit has an extremely important function if He is involved in the unpardonable sin and is thus distinct from the Father and Son.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I appreciate your extra information from the appendix. Since Acts 5:3-4 equates lying to the Holy Spirit with lying to God, would Luke 1:35 equate being born of the Spirit with being "the Son of God" (i.e., born of God)? Regardless of whether this helps/hurts trinitarianism, binitarianism, or Arianism, would the text itself equate being born of the Spirit with being the Son of God _in the same way_ that Acts 5 equates lying to the Holy Spirit with lying to God?

Comment: Also, Romans 8:26-27 is a passage that's interested me recently, so I appreciated it coming up in your answer. :)